# Powershell: Webscrape Paragraphs

Tags: html, powershell, web-scraping

I've been relatively successful using variations of the following to scrape web data.

```
$url = “https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/en-US/vulnerability/CVE-2019-1331"
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url
$response.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByClassName('css-247') | select -expand innertext
```

I cannot get the data that is stored in a paragraph tag in the url listed in the code.

```
<div class="css-247">
 <p>
     'Text I want to copy
```

I am assuming the P is not 'inner text'?  How can I grab that Text?
If I copy XPath where the text is: it's at `/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/p[1]`

If I copy cssPath I get:

`html body.ms-Fabric--isFocusHidden div#root div.ms-Fabric.root-41 div.css-43 div.ms-Stack.css-87 div.ms-Stack.css-87 div.ms-ScrollablePane.root-88 div.ms-ScrollablePane--contentContainer.contentContainer-89 div.ms-Stack.css-93 div.ms-Stack.css-110 div.ms-ScrollablePane.root-88 div.ms-ScrollablePane--contentContainer.contentContainer-89 div div div#executiveSummary.ms-Stack.ms-Card.css-136 div.ms-Stack.ms-CardSection.css-138 div.ms-Shimmer-container.root-113 div.ms-Shimmer-dataWrapper.dataWrapper-140 div.ms-StackItem.ms-CardItem.css-246 div.css-247 p`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data is dynamically retrieved from an API call returning JSON i.e. when you navigate to the URI in your question, using a browser, the browser runs Javascript which leads to additional XHR requests being made and the page being updated with that content. With your current method those requests aren't made so the desired content is not present.

You need to call the appropriate endpoint, found in the network tab of the browser, extract the relevant part of the JSON response, parse out of the html the summary:

```
$url = "https://api.msrc.microsoft.com/sug/v2.0/en-US/vulnerability/CVE-2019-1331"
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url
$data = $response | ConvertFrom-Json
$summary = $data.description
$html = New-Object -ComObject "HTMLFile"
$html.IHTMLDocument2_write($summary)
$html.firstChild | % innerText
```

I looked up writing an html string to IHTMLDocument2 here: https://paullimblog.wordpress.com/2017/08/08/ps-tip-parsing-html-from-a-local-file-or-a-string/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That grabbed the affected products.  I was trying to get the executive summary. How did you figure out which URL to grab?  The ones I tried for the executive summary (https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/en-US/vulnerability/CVE-2019-0953#executivesummary), I get an error 'ConvertFrom-Jason : Invalid JSON primitive:

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect that you want the executive summary.

Comment: Thank you for both.  I saved the other comment locally, because it was some great information that I didn't know either.   Ashamedly, I had to look up N.B. too. I learned a lot today.  Thank you again

Comment: You are welcome. If there is more than one p tag then as per link you can use `$html.all.tags("p") | % innerText`